# Hollow circular columns vs solid circular columns of exactly the same mass and length, which resist buckling better?

Tags: buckling, columns

I've seen a number of mentions in the tensegrity literature asserting (without proof or reference) that, in the context of a tensegrity rod under pure axial compression, hollow columns perform better than solid columns for the same weight.

Is this true? There must surely be papers comparing the two in a definitive and controlled way, can anyone point me towards one or more of these?

Comment: So why do cars use solid drive shafts up to a given diameter and when the propeller shafts are designed they use hollow tubes? Some easy research should answer that.

Comment: I'm trying to focus here on axial compression rather than torsion, so I'm not sure where you're heading, sorry. 

Answer (score 0):

In terms of buckling, having a larger structure is advantageous.  Things are rarely ever pure so even under "pure" axial loading, the failure mode will tend to have some lateral component.

Impurities in tangential directions reduce displacements via allowing some deformations inward (think Poisson's ratio and how materials try to expand in the perpendicular plane when compressed) for the hollow entity.  Hollow will also have material spread further apart, reducing shear (angular) stresses.

This however may not always be better.  In order to withstand high load, one may need a high displacement to be acceptable.  Resisting displacement is however often the primary purpose of structure.

Rather than seeking papers, try to model your cylinder and tube, but instead of making them straight, perhaps put the same small lateral offset to their midsections.

Answer (score 0):

- The column buckling formula is:

$$ F = \frac{ n π2 E I }{ L2}$$

where

F = allowable load (lb, N)

n = factor accounting for the end conditions

E = modulus of elastisity (lb/in2, Pa (N/m2))

L = length of column (in, m)

I = Moment of inertia (in4, m4)

- A round column "I" is:
  $$ I_x= I_y = \frac{\pi}{4}R^4$$

- R= radius of the column

Other column sections like square columns are related to the I as well.

- And a hollow column I is:

$$I_x = I_y= \frac{\pi}{4}(R_2^4- R_1^4)$$

- R2= outer radius
- R1= inner radius

So the "I" of the hollow column is smaller and it will buckle first.

However, we can note that the material used on the outer layer is much more effective in contributing to the I of the cylinder for example a column with a hole 80% its diameter has an I only approximately 40% weaker. and that can be compensated by choosing a slightly larger diameter for the column. This helps save material and ease of transport and erection.

Comment: Thanks for that! My question was actually about comparing hollow columns with solid columns of the same mass (rather than the same external radius). Numerically, I believe that hollow columns will always have a higher I than solid columns *of the same mass*, but that is far from the whole story as far as buckling goes. I'm just trying to see the whole picture here!

Comment: Mass is related to R squared. so one could use the same equations. e g, a column with 80% void is only 16% weaker for buckling. for short columns, this is not true though.